# Scheduled tasks for REST request in WSO2 ESB

Tags: web-services, rest, task, wso2-esb

I'd like to schedule tasks in WSO2 ESB in order to use restful web services and obtain, from these web services, some responses every N seconds.
In the task configuration page in WSO2 ESB configuring SOAP services is simple, but what about REST services? For example, if I want to ask some information to this web service http://maps.googleapis.com/maps, how can i configure a working task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a task, you can inject messages to RESTful Endpoints through a sequence or a proxy service. Refer `Injecting messages to RESTful Endpoints` section of [1] for more details on how to do this.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks

Comment: Thank, this example works good. Now i'd like to replay these steps with another proxy service, for example google maps mentioned above, and i don't know where to find the list of the commands i have to insert in the properties of the inSequence of the proxy service. I found this at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro but i can't retrieve information about the right usage with "properties" fields of the proxy.

Comment: Another interesting site for example is https://www.flickr.com/services/api/request.rest.html but i can't retrieve information on how to set my properties in the proxy service for sendng requests.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to define a sequence to call the REST endpoint and inject it with the scheduled task. Try the following example :

```
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="callAPI">
   <call>
      <endpoint>
         <http method="GET" uri-template="http://testAPI/test"/>
      </endpoint>
   </call>
</sequence>


<task xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
      name="testTask"
      class="org.apache.synapse.startup.tasks.MessageInjector"
      group="synapse.simple.quartz">
   <trigger interval="5"/>
   <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
             name="sequenceName"
             value="callAPI"/>
   <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks"
             name="injectTo"
             value="sequence"/>
   <property xmlns:task="http://www.wso2.org/products/wso2commons/tasks" name="message">
      <test xmlns=""/>
   </property>
</task>
```